# Getting a typemismatch error when trying to pass boolean argument

Tags: java, arrays, types, mismatch

In my shuffle deck function,

```
    public void shuffleDeck(){              
        Random rng = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < shuffledDeck.length; i++){
            deckOfCards[i] = shuffledDeck[rng.nextInt(52)].setFlag(true);
```

I want to run through all 52 cards, and shuffle them be randomizing their location to another array. However, in order to prevent the same card from being overwritten, I have written a setFlag function in another class that takes in a boolean argument, and then I will use that to check if the flag is set and so forth. However, at the last line, I'm getting the error 
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Card"...not at all sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Card c = shuffledDeck[rng nextInt(52)]; c.setFlag(true); deckOfCards[i]=c;

Comment: setFlag is a function and shuffledDeck is an array. You can't invoke a function using an array.

Comment: then how come this works?deckOfCards[cardCount].setSuit(suit[suitCount]); deckOfCards[cardCount].setFace(face[faceCount], faceValue);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function **shuffleDeck** has to be invoked with no arguments, like `shuffleDeck();`, anyway, as people in comments have said, you are trying to invoke in a way that is not possible: `shuffledDeck[rng.nextInt(52)]`.

Any function can't be invoked with the syntax that you have used.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you're saying, then how come this works?deckOfCards[cardCount].setSuit(suit[suitCount]);
deckOfCards[cardCount].setFace(face[faceCount], faceValue);

Comment: I don't know what is **setSuit** and **setFace**, and if you are invoking well.